# block of text shows up before expected result when running kotlin file (":\JDK installed here\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:D:\Kotlin\IntelliJ IDEA..."

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

the problem I'm facing (Result of execution):

```
D:\JDK installed here\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:D:\Kotlin\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=62997:D:\Kotlin\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\untitled3\build\classes\kotlin\main;C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.4.30\d10d1e10f47006ee08162dde039e38ac487de4ac\kotlin-stdlib-1.4.30.jar;C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlinx\kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm\1.4.2\4b9c6b2de7cabfb2c9ad7a5c709b1ddb7bbfd2ad\kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.4.2.jar;C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.4.30\bb9a3173350f55732416ee27956ea8f9b81f4dbb\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.4.30.jar;C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains\annotations\13.0\919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9\annotations-13.0.jar TestingKt
Start
Hello
Stop
```

and as you can guess the expected output would be just the "Start hello stop" part, is there some option or a way to hide that text?

Comment: hi, interesting, it looks like the command that the script i running is being echo'd. you could modify the script to not echo commands